# Cherry tree fungus

Tags: trees, plant-health, diseases

I’ve got a cherry tree of some variety (at least, I think that’s what it is). Last winter, some black fungus clusters started forming on some of the branches. I figured I should snip them all off the tree and managed to get quite a few of them before spring, hoping that the fungus wouldn’t spread.

Well, it’s back this winter and it’s on some branches that I can’t reach, as well as also being present on a knot where the previous owner had removed a low branch.

Is there some kind of treatment for my poor tree aside from cutting out all the fungus?

[image: fungus][image: fungus][image: bark]

Comment: can you add a photo or two of this fungus please?

Comment: is it a burl, or chaga?

Comment: I do not understand either of those words, so I’ll have to get back to you on that.

Comment: That’s a yes to chaga.